# separate each row of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and want to create an excel file for each line on that dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import math


df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]) # uncreative input values for 10 columns
NUMBER_OF_SPLITS = 10

fileOpens = [open(f"out{i}.xlsx","w") for i in range(NUMBER_OF_SPLITS)]
fileWriters = [xlsx.writer(v, lineterminator='\n') for v in fileOpens]
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    fileWriters[math.floor((i/df.shape[0])*NUMBER_OF_SPLITS)].writerow(row.tolist())
for file in fileOpens:
    file.close()
```

Comment: Please explain a bit more: What is the problem? What doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried using in the iterrows `pd.to_excel()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    content = b.to_frame().T
    content.to_excel(file_name_list[i])
```

or if you don't have a file's list then you could simply:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    content = b.to_frame().T
    content.to_excel("file number" + str(i))
```